# The state of an inedible food

Tags: food

If you leave the food for a long time out of refrigerator, something happens to the food and makes it smelly and inedible.

What is that state of the food called in English?

Comment: "Spoiled" (as submitted by SamuelVimes) is very common. We also say "went bad", a lot. If you want to be more colorful, "putrefied" is one of my favorites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you can say that the food has ***spoiled***

According to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com)

[***spoil***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spoiled?showCookiePolicy=true)

> verb
>
> Word forms:  spoils,  spoiling,  spoilt,  spoiled
>
> 3)  (intransitive) (of perishable substances) to become unfit for consumption or use   ⇒ "the fruit must be eaten before it spoils"

Comment: Just to add - a more colloquial expression (at least in BRE) would be "Gone off."

Comment: I would say *spoiled* requires an outward change in appearance or smell; it is not used with every kind of food. Meat or milk can spoil, as can fruits and vegetables, but I can't think of anyone who says that eggs *spoil*, as their rottenness is only comprehended once they are cracked. Neither does bread *spoil* in my experience, as it does not generally putrefy or start to smell bad. But you can say of all of these that they *turn* or *go bad*.

Comment: @choster I have to say that (in this case) I disagree with what you say. In my opinion, if the food is no longer fit for consumption, if it is no longer fresh, then it has spoiled, regardless of its external appearance. For example, some strains of botulism will not change the odour, colour or taste of the food they colonize, yet that food is no longer safe for consumption. And, while it is true that eggs may rot and that bread may go stale or mouldy (and I agree that those terms are correct), in the end, in all of those cases the food has spoiled (at least, that is my opinion).

Comment: @choster As a side note, I have heard the term 'spoil' before when talking about eggs, milk or bread and, in fact, a quick search with google turns out many examples

Answer (score 6):

maybe also rotten...
a full box of rotten fruit

Answer (score 4):

You can use the adjective ***bad***. The following is taken from the [Longman English Dictionary Online](http://www.ldoceonline.com/):

[**bad**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bad_1)

```
9) food that is bad is not safe to eat because it has decayed:

 - bad fish

 - This milk has gone bad.
```